# incompatible return type

Tags: c, incompatibletypeerror

I have a question what does a incompatible return type error mean? I keep getting an error that is saying this and I've changed my code multiple times and nothing. Can any one help me please and thank you.

Im getting the error at :

```
circular_list.c: In function ‘circ_list_iterator’:
circular_list.c:116:( return lst ? NEXT(lst) : NULL; )error: incompatible types in return
circular_list.c:118:( return (lastreturn == lst) ? NULL : NEXT(lastreturn); )error: incompatible types in return
circular_list.c:119:( } )warning: control reaches end of non-void function
circular_list.c: In function ‘circ_length’:
circular_list.c:127:( while( (lastreturn = circ_list_iterator(lst, lastreturn)) != NULL))error: incompatible types in assignment
circular_list.c: In function ‘nth_node’:
circular_list.c:136:( return NULL; )error: incompatible types in return
circular_list.c:138:( return lst; )error: incompatible types in return
circular_list.c:145:( return (number != 0) ? NULL : tmp; )error: incompatible types in return
```

circular_list.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "globals.h"
#include "circular_list.h"

typedef struct node *list_rep;

typedef struct node {
    generic_ptr datapointer;
    list_rep    next;
} node;


#define DATA(lst) (((list_rep) (lst))->datapointer)
#define NEXT(lst) (((list_rep) (lst))->next)

#define TOLIST(list_rep) ((list)    (list_rep))
#define TOREP(lst)       ((list_rep)(lst))

#define TOLISTPTR(list_rep_ptr) ((list *)    (list_rep_ptr))
#define TOREPPTR(lst_ptr)       ((list_rep *)(lst_ptr))

static status allocate_node (list_rep *p_lst, generic_ptr data)
{
    list lst = (list) malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (lst == NULL)
            return ERROR;

    *p_lst = lst;
    DATA(lst) = data;
    NEXT(lst) = NULL;

    return OK;
}

static void free_node (list *p_lst)
{
    free(*p_lst);
    *p_lst = NULL;

extern status init_circ_list (list *p_lst)
{
    *p_lst = NULL;
    return OK;
}
extern bool   empty_circ_list (list lst)
{
    return (lst == NULL) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

status circ_insert (list *p_lst, generic_ptr data)
{
    list_rep lst, *p_lst_rep = TOREPPTR(p_lst);

    if (allocate_node(&lst, data) == ERROR)
            return ERROR;

    if (empty_circ_list(*p_lst)) {
            NEXT(lst) = lst;
            *p_lst_rep = lst;
    } else {
            NEXT(lst) = NEXT(*p_lst_rep);
            NEXT(*p_lst_rep) = lst;
    }
    return OK;
}

status circ_length     (list lst)
{
    list lastreturn;
    int length;

    length = 0;
    lastreturn = NULL;
    while( (lastreturn = circ_list_iterator(lst, lastreturn)) != NULL)
            length++;
    return length;
}
status nth_node        (list lst, int number)
{
    list tmp;

    if (empty_circ_list(lst) == TRUE)
            return NULL;
    if (number == -1)
            return lst;

    tmp = lst;
    do {
            tmp = NEXT(tmp);
            number--;
    } while (number > 0 && tmp != lst);
    return (number != 0) ? NULL : tmp;

    return 0;
}
status circ_traverse   (list lst, status     (*p_func_f)())
{
    list tmp;

    if (empty_circ_list(lst) == TRUE)
            return OK;

    tmp = lst;
    do {
            tmp = NEXT(tmp);
            if ((*p_func_f)(DATA(tmp)) == ERROR)
                    return ERROR;
    } while (tmp != lst) ;
return OK;
}
```

circular_list.h

```
#include "globals.h"

#ifndef _CIRCULAR_LIST_H
#define _CIRCULAR_LIST_H

typedef list lastreturn;
ABSTRACT_TYPE(list);

extern status init_circ_list  (list *p_lst);
extern bool   empty_circ_list (list lst);
extern status circ_insert     (list *p_lst, generic_ptr data);
extern status circ_append     (list *p_lst, generic_ptr data);
extern status circ_delete     (list *p_lst, generic_ptr *p_data);
extern status circ_delete_node(list *p_lst, list node);
extern status circ_list_iterator (list lst, list lastreturn);
extern status circ_length        (list lst);
extern status nth_node           (list lst, int number);
extern status circ_traverse      (list lst, status     (*p_func_f)());

extern generic_ptr  circ_head(list lst);
extern list         circ_tail(list lst);

#endif
```

globals.h

```
#ifndef _GLOBALS_H
#define _GLOBALS_H

typedef enum {OK, ERROR} status;
typedef enum {FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1} bool;

typedef void *generic_ptr;

typedef unsigned char byte;

#define ABSTRACT_TYPE(t)    
typedef void *(t)

#endif
```

Comment: in circ_length, you are supposed to return a status, but instead you are returning an int.

Comment: I'm getting numerous compile errors under gcc, but not that message.

Comment: Those are the only errors im getting im using gcc -Wall -g -ansi -pedantic  -c circular_list.c to compile my code

Comment: i tried changing the return type and it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 5):

This looks wrong:

```
status nth_node(list lst, int number)
{
    list tmp;

    ...

    return (number != 0) ? NULL : tmp;

    ...
}
```

`tmp` is not a `status`.